# grep regular expression solution (greedy not working)

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep, regular-expression

I have the following text in the data.txt file

```
:MENU1
0. public
1. admin
2. webmail

:SYNTAX
! opt1, ... :

:ERROR1
Error #1, blah... blah.. blah...
Please do ...

:ERROR2
Error #2 ...
```

and I want to use a regular expression (PERL syntax) to extract the part from `:MENU1` to the next first `:`, but dropping `MENU1` and the last `:` from the result.

Been trying several regex's but in the closest solution I got
I can't put the 'greedy' option to work and cant't discard the last ":"

```
grep -Poz "^:MENU1\K[\w\W]*:"
```

this works with grep ... 
but brings all the text until the last ":" ...
I want only until the next first ":" after `:MENU1`:

```
0. public
1. admin
2. webmail
```

(note the final blank line)

Comment: Do you also want the blank lines? There's a `\n` after `:MENU1` and before the first `:`, should those be included? Please [edit] your question and show us your desired output.

Comment: Yes.. I want the blank lines except the first after "MENU1"... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern `*:` will match everything until the last `:`.  To stop at the next `:` you need `*?:`.  E.g.:

```
% grep -Poz '^:MENU1\K[\w\W]*?:' data.txt 

0. public
1. admin
2. webmail

:
```

You can strip the first line by matching the newline before your `\K`. E.g.:

```
% grep -Poz '^:MENU1\n\K[\w\W]*?:' data.txt 
0. public
1. admin
2. webmail

:
```

To eat the empty line and the `:` you can match and discard that text.  E.g.:

```
% grep -Poz '^:MENU1\n\K[\w\W]*?(?=\n+:)' data.txt 
0. public
1. admin
2. webmail
```

next we can simplify your character class, to match on anything but `:`:

```
% grep -Poz '^:MENU1\n\K[^:]*?(?=\n+:)' data.txt 
0. public
1. admin
2. webmail
```

And finally we can rewrite the initial part of the match:

```
% grep -Poz '(?<=:MENU1\n)[^:]*?(?=\n+:)' data.txt 
0. public
1. admin
2. webmail
```

This is similar to what @terdon came up with, but this takes care of the blank lines without another call to grep.

This final regex makes use of *look-around* assertions.  The `(?<=pattern)` is a `look-behind` assertion that lets you match the `pattern` but not include it as part of the output.  The `(?=pattern)` is a `look-ahead` assertion and lets us match on the trailing pattern without including it in the output.

Answer (score 2):

What about: `grep -Poz "^:MENU1\K[^:]*"`?

Comment: Note: the [^:] means any character but ':'

Comment: with -P (PERL) flag the ^ means the start of the line...<br>
and there the ^is working OK... <br>
only problem is the greed thing not working

Comment: To exclude empty line from the beginning `":MENU1\n\K[^:]*"`

Comment: @ZEE: agreed, but not inside square brackets

Comment: @ZEE: default perl behavior is to match the longest string, if you want a greedy pattern you have to use the '?' modifier like `grep "^:MENU1\K[\w\W]*?:"`

Comment: Thanx man... do you know how to remove the last ":" in the result...

Answer (score 2):

@Herbert's solution is probably the simplest, but you could also use lookarounds:

```
$ grep -Poz '(?<=:MENU1\n)[^:]*' file 
0. public
1. admin
2. webmail
```